# access var from enum inside a class

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I've following code but unable to access app from Enum

```
open class Foo {
    private var app: Bar  
    enum Directions: String {
        case north = "NorthId"
        case south = "SouthId"
        case east = "EastId"
        case west = "WestId"
        case northEast = "NorthEastId"
        case northWest = "NorthWestId"
        case southEast = "SouthEastId"
        case southWest = "SouthWestId"
        var dir: String {
            switch self {
            case .north, .south, .east, .west 
              return app.getDirection[self.rawValue]
            case northEast, northWest, southEast, southWest
              return app.getCoordinates[self.rawValue]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here issue is app is not accessible inside enum Directions. How can I access class variable app inside the another class variable Enum Directions.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a [mcve]

Comment: Where is your getDirection property? What type is it? Where is your Bar declaration? It will impossible to help you if you don't provide a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Thanks @LeoDabus, let me recreate full example and will post

Comment: What is getDirection and getCoordinates, perhaps you can make them static?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I access class variable app inside the another class variable Enum Directions.

There's a mistake in this question. `app` *isn't* a class variable. It's an instance variable that belongs to instances of the class `Foo`. That is, there's one value `app` per object of `Foo`.

This then begs the question, if the `Directions` enum was trying to access an `app` value, which one should it use?

Put another way, a name is an instance variables of humans. It makes sense to ask "What is the name of this person?". However, it doesn't make sense to ask "What is the name of Person?"... well... which person? Yet, this is exactly what you're trying to do in `Directions` enum.

It's hard recommend a solution without more context about what you're trying to achieve, but I can confidently say that it would be incorrect for the `Directions` enum (which is just a simple little type that describes 8 cardinal directions) to do anything at all involving an "app", or any other such high-level concepts.